# How to call the method of inner class from another class ?

Tags: android, class, static, nested

```
public class MusicService extends Service  implements MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener{


private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private int length = 0;

public MusicService() { }

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
     MusicService getService()
     {
        return MusicService.this;
     }
}
```

I want to call getService method from anothere class which is shown as below

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

// splash screen timer
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT= 3000;


// for music player in background 

private boolean mIsBound = false;
private MusicService mServ;
private ServiceConnection Scon =new ServiceConnection(){

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder
     binder) {

        mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder).getService();


    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        mServ = null;
    }



    };
```

it shows syntax error in line  mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder).getService();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
    mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder)binder).getService();
```

instead of

```
    mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder).getService();
```

to initialize `MusicService mServ` from  onServiceConnected

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 'binder)'
Change:

```
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder).getService();
```

For:

```
mServ = ((MusicService.ServiceBinderbinder)binder).getService();
```